# my first MySQL procedure ...mysterious error

Tags: mysql

This is my first MySQL proc after much experience with MS SQL procs.  In MySQL Workbench, the only alert is on the End line for the whole proc, but it gives no specifics.

After working my way through a few other things, all I'm left with now is this error...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

By the way, I had @ on all my variables but became convinced that was an issue.  Not sure if it was/is?

Here's the procedure...

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `dbname`.`ImportAccountToGravityForm` ()
BEGIN

  DECLARE intForm_id INTEGER;
  DECLARE intLead_id_current INT;
  DECLARE fltField_number_current FLOAT;
  DECLARE vcrValue_current VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE intWeb_Site_Member_ID INT; -- id in import table
  DECLARE vcrValue2 VARCHAR(200);  -- SCHOOL
  DECLARE vcrValue7 VARCHAR(200);  -- ADDRESS LINE 1
  DECLARE vcrValue8 VARCHAR(200);  -- CITY
  DECLARE vcrValue9 VARCHAR(200); -- STATE
  DECLARE vcrValue10 VARCHAR(200); -- ZIP
  DECLARE vcrValue11 VARCHAR(200); -- COUNTRY
  DECLARE vcrValue12 VARCHAR(200);  -- NON-STUDENT/STUDENT
  DECLARE vcrValue13 VARCHAR(200);  -- CLASS OF
  DECLARE vcrValue14 VARCHAR(200);  -- DESCRIPTION
  DECLARE vcrValue16 VARCHAR(200);  -- EMAIL
  DECLARE vcrValue17 VARCHAR(200);  -- AWARD
  DECLARE vcrValue19 VARCHAR(200);  -- SUBMITED BY - FULL NAME
  DECLARE vcrValue20 VARCHAR(200);  -- SUBMITTED BY - MAIL
  DECLARE vcrValue23 VARCHAR(200);  -- YEAR AWARDED
  DECLARE vcrValue24_6 VARCHAR(200);  -- FIRST NAME
  DECLARE vcrValue24_3 VARCHAR(200);  -- LAST NAME
  DECLARE vcrValue25 VARCHAR(200);  -- TITLE

  SET intForm_id = 2;
  SET intLead_id_current = -1;
  SET vcrValue19 = 'Import from YM';  -- SUBMITED BY - FULL NAME
  SET vcrValue20 = '';  -- SUBMITTED BY - MAIL
  SET vcrValue12 = '';  -- STUDENT/ALUMNI
  SET vcrValue14 = '';  -- DESCRIPTION

  SELECT e.Web_Site_Member_ID, e.School, e.Home_Address_Line1, e.Home_City, e.Home_State_Abbrev, e.Home_Postal_Code,
     e.Home_Country, e.Class_of, e.Email_Address, e.Membership, e.Year_award_or_scholarship_received,
     e.First_Name, e.Last_Name, e.Title
  INTO intWeb_Site_Member_ID,
            vcrValue2,  -- SCHOOL
            vcrValue7,  -- ADDRESS LINE 1
            vcrValue8,  -- CITY
            vcrValue9,  -- STATE
            vcrValue10,  -- ZIP
            vcrValue11,  -- COUNTRY
            vcrValue13,  -- CLASS OF
            vcrValue16,  -- EMAIL
            vcrValue17,  -- AWARD
            vcrValue23,  -- YEAR AWARDED
            vcrValue24_6,   -- FIRST NAME
            vcrValue24_3,   -- LAST NAME
            vcrValue25   -- TITLE
    FROM Export_fromYM_2012_06_25 e
    WHERE e.Imported <> 'Y' AND e.Member_Type_Code = 'Student/Alumni'
    ORDER BY e.Web_Site_Member_ID ASC;

    INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead
        (form_id, date_created, ip, source_url, user_agent)
    VALUES
        (1, NOW(), '', 'import');

    SET intLead_id_current = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    IF intLead_id_current > 0 THEN
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 2, vcrValue2);

            INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 7, vcrValue7);

            INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 8, vcrValue8);

            INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 9, vcrValue9);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 10, vcrValue10);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 11, vcrValue11);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 12, vcrValue12);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 13, vcrValue13);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 14, vcrValue14);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 16, vcrValue16);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 17, vcrValue17);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 19, vcrValue19);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 20, vcrValue20);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 23, vcrValue23);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 24.6, vcrValue24_6);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 24.3, vcrValue24_3);

              INSERT INTO wp_hpvyvb_rg_lead_detail
              (lead_id, form_id, field_number, value)
            VALUES
              (intLead_id_current, intForm_id, 25, vcrValue25);


        UPDATE Export_fromYM_2012_06_25 SET Imported = 'Y', CustomFieldsMemberID = intLead_id_current WHERE @intWeb_Site_Member_ID = Web_Site_Member_ID;

     END; -- IF

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: "This is my first MySQL proc" When I write my first ever program in any new language I always start with something simple like "Hello World" and get that working first. Once I've got that, I then slowly add more code to get it to do what I want, testing it at each step. Have you tried breaking your problem down into smaller parts and getting those working first? I can't imagine writing 100+ lines of code completely correctly on my first attempt in a language I've never used before. I'd be happy if I could do that in a language I *am* familiar with!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I needed no 'Begin' 'End' on the if statement but instead an 'End If'

thanks!